# SavedModel file does not exist at: saved_model.pb/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, path, fastapi

I wanted to use a saved model within a fastAPI server. The model and the corresponding python file are both located at ./server/routes directory. But whenever i try to start the server using:

```
uvicorn main:app --reload
```

I get an error saying

```
SavedModel file does not exist at: saved_model.pb/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}.
```

What could be the reason? I am a novice at both deep learning and fastAPI, so consider that please.

The fastAPI code is this:

```py
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
import numpy as np
import cv2

app = FastAPI()

model_path = '/home/sharif/Desktop/Ekunjo-A-Gardening-Solution/server/routes/saved_model.pb'

model = tf.saved_model.load("saved_model.pb")  

@app.post("/predict")
async def predict_image(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    contents = await file.read()

    # Convert the image to a format compatible with the model
    nparr = np.fromstring(contents, np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(nparr, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
    img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224)) 
    img = img / 255.0  # Normalize the image

    # Make predictions
    input_data = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)  # Adding a batch dimension
    prediction = model.signatures["serving_default"](tf.constant(input_data))["dense"].numpy()

    # Return the prediction result
    return JSONResponse(content={"prediction": prediction.tolist()})
```

Comment: You need pass the folder as parameter, not the actual file.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy i did that and it produces a new error saying: "FileNotFoundError(
FileNotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for ./variables/variables
 You may be trying to load on a different device from the computational device. Consider setting the `experimental_io_device` option in `tf.saved_model.LoadOptions` to the io_device such as '/job:localhost'."